# Bootstrap 3.3.5 Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am trying to get the Bootstrap Datepicker to work on my website but the button seems to be disabled and doesn't do anything when i click on it or the input form box here is my test code I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. i am using bootstrap 3.3.5

```
   <!DOCTYPE html><html>
   <head>
   <title>Testing</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            });
        });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>
  <h1>BootStrap Datepicker</h1>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id='datepicker'>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthdate yyyy/mm/dd">
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                   </span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </form>
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="panel">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Bootstrap-datepicker set date sample</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputDate">Some special date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputDate">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the javascript file

var firstDayOfMonth = function() {
    // your special logic...
    return 5;
};

```
var d = new Date();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();
var startDate = new Date(currYear,currMonth,firstDayOfMonth());
$('#exampleInputDate').datepicker('setDate',startDate);
```

This should work perfectly

[here is the plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/JBh3x/3/)